# How to view the keyboard shortcuts window from Unity on Xfce?

Tags: unity, keyboard, shortcut-keys, xfce

Is it possible to view the keyboard shortcuts window accessible with the <kbd>Super</kbd> key from unity also in Xfce? If yes, is it possible to change the contents of the window?

I would like to have a pop-up window with my cheatsheet of eg. vim commands when I press the <kbd>Super</kbd> key. What would be a good way to accomplish it? The functionality should be like the keyboard shortcuts cheatsheet in Unity invoked by the <kbd>Super</kbd> key.

[image]

Comment: System-wide shortcuts are available and customizable in Xfce (Xubuntu) from **Settings > Keyboard > Application Shortcuts** and **Settings > Window Manager > Keyboard** menu.

Comment: What I am asking about is the Unity feature.

Comment: Unity and Xfce is 2 separate desktop environment with separate keyboard shortcuts. You can install and use Unity 7 on Ubuntu 18.04 if you prefer Unity shortcuts.

Comment: I cannot use unity since my. Pc is ancient. But i was looking for similar feature like in unity that would display system shortcuts after a single press of a key.

Comment: I added the feature screenshot to be more precise. I am looking for such feature.